# Interpretation of a weakly compact set of functions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I'm having trouble really grasping the idea of a weakly compact set. The set I have under consideration is a set of functions $M_c$, where

$$M_c=\{f:W(f)\leq c\},$$

where $c\geq0$ and $W(f)$ is a non-negative real-valued functional. In my reference it is stated that: "$M_c$ is a weakly compact set"

I have googled out that:

- Weakly compact set is a compact set with weak topology
- Weak topology on set $X$ is the coarsest topology that makes a set of functions $\mathcal{F}$ continuous
- A topology $\mathcal{T}_1$ is coarser than topology $\mathcal{T}_2$ on set $X$ if $\mathcal{T}_1\subseteq\mathcal{T}_2$

So if I have interpreted everything correctly, in plain words this means that:

> $M_c$ is a compact set of functions with a topology (i.e. a set of
>   subsets of $M_c$) with smallest cardinality that makes the functionals
>   $W\in\mathcal{F}$ continuous. In other words $M_c$ is a compact set
>   such that the number $m$ of possible subsets of functions I can draw
>   from it that make functionals $W\in\mathcal{F}$ continuous, is as
>   small as possible. This means that there is no compact set of
>   functions $N_c$ such that the number $n$ of possible subsets of $N_c$
>   which make the functionals $W\in\mathcal{F}$ continuous would have $n < m$.

My question is: Have I interpreted a weakly compact set correctly? If not could I get an explanation for it? What $M_c$ really is? What does it contain? Example? :)

Thank you for any help =)

P.S. Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: Here's a non-mathematical intuitive explanation. Open sets are meant to say which points are close. Whenever 2 points are included in a many open sets, they are close to each other. So many open sets mean that two points are more likely to be "far" of each other. Compact sets are sets whose points are "close" to each other. If you take a topology with many open sets, it will be difficult for a set to be compact. The idea of weak topology is to select very few open sets, so that there will be more compact sets.

Comment: Thank you for your help @HerbertQuain that helped :)

Comment: One technical issue with your statement is that you really can't think in terms of the *number* of continuous functions or the *number* of open sets. There are "fewer" open sets in a coarser space in the sense that every set which is open continuous in the coarser space is open in the finer space, and that there exist open sets in the finer space which are not open in the coarser space. The actual cardinality of these two sets is usually the same (except when one topology is "much" weaker than the other).

Comment: Thank you @Ian appreciate the help :-)